# What's the name of this board game about a Middle East oil war?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to find a board game which I knew when I was a kid. Nobody let me play it.

It's played in the Middle East. It has oil pipelines to link territories, oil tanker ships, perhaps an oil drill, dictator (a hand), artillery (tank), a head piece (sorry I don't remember what it is), and if I'm not wrong it has a king and a warrior or spy too. I don't remember if it had money, dice, etc.

The objective, if I remember correctly, was to gain power, economy control, etc. It has **some** similarities to Risk and Diplomacy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With help from [Pat Ludwig's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/834/whats-the-name-of-this-board-game-about-middle-orient-oil-war/868#868) I found out the right game.

It's **[The Game of Nations](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1958/the-game-of-nations)**.

[image: Board]
[image: Pieces]

This game probably was release to exploit the first oil big crisis in 1972. Good to know that the world changed :-)

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, to let people know that the question has been resolved!

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad you found it.

Comment: @Brian: I will in 2 days when system allow.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that it doesn't allow you to do it as soon as you answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple guesses, I'm not sure either matches everything you listed though.

**[Oil: The Great Adventure](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/12237/oil-the-great-adventure)**

[image]

**[Petróleo](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22614/petroleo)**

[image]

A couple GeekLists may have what you are looking for if I missed the mark.

- [Let's Play the Oil War](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/14564/lets-play-the-oil-game-)
- [Oil Exploration Games](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/42079/oil-exploration-games)